# Impossibility to install toripchanger with pip

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, tor

I am trying to install the library [toripchanger](https://github.com/DusanMadar/TorIpChanger).

I did once:

```
C:\Users\Machintruc>pip install toripchanger
```

output:

```
Collecting toripchanger
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement toripchanger (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for toripchanger
You are using pip version 18.0, however version 19.0.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

So I updated pip:

```
C:\Users\Machintruc>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Collecting pip
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d7/41/34dd96bd33958e52cb4da2f1bf0818e396514fd4f4725a79199564cd0c20/pip-19.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.4MB)

100% |################################| 1.4MB 437kB/s
Installing collected packages: pip
  Found existing installation: pip 18.0
    Uninstalling pip-18.0:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-18.0
Successfully installed pip-19.0.2
```

I tried again to install:

```
C:\Users\Machintruc>pip install toripchanger
```

output:

```
DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. 
A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting toripchanger
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement toripchanger (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for toripchanger
```

I am not sure to upgrade Python will be usefull, besides I won't to debug all my scripts because I upgraded Python, 2020 is far away today.
`No matching distribution found for toripchanger` does mean it does not exist anymore anyway?

Comment: ```pip install toripchanger``` worked on my machine (Python 3.5)

Comment: Ok, I guess it is a matter of Python version then. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It exists, but the PyPi version only supports python3x. You can check out the relevant [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/toripchanger/). On the left there is an entry "Programming Language", which only lsits `python::3`. That is why your `pip` cannot find a version that matches your setup.

Consider using virtual environments if you need to use both python version on the same machine

Comment: If I do use [toripchanger](https://pypi.org/project/toripchanger/) in a project written in [scrapy 1.6.0](https://pypi.org/project/Scrapy/) it is normally compatible right?

Comment: Since scrapy also supports python 3.4+, you should be able to get your project running using both modules yes

Comment: I know I have a version of python 3 in my anaconda folder. I've got `python3.dll`, `python36.dll`, `python36.pdb` in it. Does it means I do not have to install python 3 again no?